# Java HttpURLConnection issue: Server redirected too many times

Tags: java

I'm working with Java 1.7.

When I test the request with Postman in Firefox, I get a response status : 200, and the Json response is good.

When I test it with my Java application, I get this Exception:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)

Here is my java code:

```
try{
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/ws");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    con.setRequestProperty("token", "mytokenvalue");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception is thrown in this line:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: So why is your server sending more than 20 redirects? Do you know? try to use some http sniffer to see what its sending back.

Comment: Looks like a redirect loop. What is your server routes configuration?

Comment: Are you using any kind of authentication?  If so, maybe you'll find useful this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022934/getting-java-net-protocolexception-server-redirected-too-many-times-error

Comment: thanks Marco, good call !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set this property before you open the connection:

`HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);`