# "Server redirected too many times" when connecting through Tor in java

Tags: java, http-redirect, tor, silvertunnel

I'm trying to read a website through Tor in a java app with the silvertunnel-ng library. The connection seems to get build (log says "To start completed!"), but when I try to read the site I get a

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times (3)
```

The test code is this:

```
String torCheck = "https://check.torproject.org/?lang=en_US";
URLStreamHandler handler = TorTools.buildTorHandler();
String result = "";
try {
    URL url = new URL(null, torCheck, handler);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
    System.setProperty("http.maxRedirects", "20");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while (br.read() != -1)
        result += br.readLine() + "\n";
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
} finally {
    ...
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Apparently the httpRedirects property doesn't get set since the stacktrace still says "(3)", but I have no idea why.

Adding the CookieHandler was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022934/getting-java-net-protocolexception-server-redirected-too-many-times-error), but to no avail.

The Tor handler is build with this method:

```
import org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.adapter.url.NetlibURLStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.api.NetFactory;
import org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.api.NetLayer;
import org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.api.NetLayerIDs;

public static URLStreamHandler buildTorHandler() {
    NetLayer netLayer = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TOR);
    netLayer.waitUntilReady();
    NetlibURLStreamHandlerFactory factory = new NetlibURLStreamHandlerFactory(false);
    factory.setNetLayerForHttpHttpsFtp(netLayer);
    return factory.createURLStreamHandler("http");
}
```

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might have to set the system property before opening the connection.

Comment: @immibis Same result:(