# How to resolve: Server redirected too many times?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, protocolexception

Looked through stackoverflow for resolutions, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022934/getting-java-net-protocolexception-server-redirected-too-many-times-error) but that didn't help.

Getting this exception

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1932)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at GetMailStatus.main(GetMailStatus.java:27)
```

for this block of code that's trying to access an InformedDelivery url with credentials

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Base64;


public class GetMailStatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL ("https://informeddelivery.usps.com/.........");
            String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("xxxx:yyyy").getBytes("UTF-8"));
            CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(msCookieManager);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

            InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in   =
                    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The code was modified based on the referenced stackoverflow discussion.  I'm assuming I'm still not managing cookies correctly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: After 20 redirects, you can rest assured that the client hangs in a redirect loop.

Comment: Maybe read the [documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/general-api-developer-guide.htm#_Toc24631959), to begin with?

Comment: I had originally intended to use the api's in the referenced documentation, but it only provides package tracking.  I had to obtain information about regular first class mail, so it seemed that the only option was to parse the informed delivery web pages.  Is it possible to cleanly handle the redirect loop via cookie management, or am I just out of luck?